# How to do cross_modality_pretrained in Keras: set different shape weights

Tags: keras

I am doing cross_modality_pretrain in keras.
I use InceptionResNetv2 pretrained model, and get weights of conv2d_1, which shape is (3 3 3 32) (height, width, channels, outputs)

```
model_base = InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

weight = model_base.get_weights()
weight_conv2d_1 = weight[0]
weight_conv2d_1 = np.mean(weight_conv2d_1, axis=2, keepdims=True)
```

I change it to (3 3 20 32)

```
for i in range(20):
    if i == 0:
        weight_change = np.concatenate((weight_conv2d_1,), axis=2)
    else:
        weight_change = np.concatenate((weight_change, weight_conv2d_1), axis=2)
```

Now, i want to set the new weight ,

```
weight[0] = weight_change
model_base.set_weights(weight)
```

But, i get error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (3, 3, 10, 32) for Tensor u'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(3, 3, 3, 32)'
```

How can i solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, the error is `set_weight` input should has the same shape of `get_weight`, however they are (3 3 3 32) and (3 3 20 32).

Second, I tried to solve it by changing model configuration parameter `model.weights()`, changing the model configuration parameter from (3 3 3 32) to (3 3 20 32). `model.weights()`return `list[tf.Variable < shape (3 3 3 32)>]`.In python, type `list` is mutable, however i failed, i can not change it. How can i solve it? Thank you !

Finally, I solve the problem by `model.get_config` to get configuration parameter, change it and rebuild a new model by `Model.from_config()`.